# Using Fastify preHandler middleware

Tags: node.js, typescript, middleware, clean-architecture, fastify

Passing a middleware to authenticate user before accessing this route.

When I'm passing `tokenController.authUser` as a middleware `tokenService` inside `tokenController` is `undefined`. However when I run this method as a function inside the route instead of a middleware it works fine.

```
server.post('/api/admin/test', { preHandler: [tokenController.authUser] }, async (request: any, reply: any) => {
    return null
});
```

Token Controller :-

```
import { Users } from "@prisma/client";
import ITokenService from "../../services/tokenService/ITokenService";
import ITokenController from "./ITokenController";

export default class TokenController implements ITokenController {
    private readonly tokenService: ITokenService;
    constructor(_tokenService: ITokenService) {
        this.tokenService = _tokenService;
    }

    async authUser(request: any, reply: any): Promise<Users | Error> {
        const authHeader = request.headers['authorization'];
        const token = authHeader && authHeader.split(' ')[1];
        if (token === null)
            return reply.code(401);
        try {
            const result = await this.tokenService.verifyToken(token);
            console.log(result);
            return result;
        }
        catch (e) {
            reply.code(401);
            return new Error("Error");
        }
    }
}
```

Token Service :-

```
import { Users } from "@prisma/client";
import ITokenService from "./ITokenService";

export default class TokenService implements ITokenService {
    private readonly sign: Function;
    private readonly verify: Function;
    private readonly secretKey: string;
    constructor(sign: Function, verify: Function, _secretKey: string) {
        this.sign = sign;
        this.verify = verify;
        this.secretKey = _secretKey;
    }

    public async generateToken(user: Users): Promise<string> {
        return await this.sign({ user }, this.secretKey);
    }

    public async verifyToken(token: string): Promise<Users | Error> {
        const result = await this.verify(token, this.secretKey);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: HOw do you instantiate the `tokenController` var?

Comment: All objects are being instantiated in a container, instantiating isn't a problem because it works fine when not passed as a middleware

Comment: `export default class TokenController` requires to run `new TokenController()` somewhere

Comment: Did that in another file called container.js. All objects have been instantiated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For some reason making a separate middleware function and calling `tokenController.authUser` inside that method works fine.

```
const middleware = (_req, _res, next) => {
  console.log('middleware');
  next()
}


server.post('/api/admin/test', { preHandler: [middleware] }, async (request: any, reply: any) => {
    return null
});
```